# Glitch with Unidentified Legendaries

Tags: diablo-iii-console

A friend of mine that has rekindled his interest in Diablo 3 has also rekindled mine. He's begun telling me that there is a glitch present on the PS4 version of the game that if one has more than 4 unidentified legendary (orange or set items) items in their inventory, the chance of more legendaries dropping increases.

Is there any merit to his statements? I tried what he said, and although it seemed like more dropped, it may have just been circumstance. I may not be searching for this correctly either, since all I can find is old videos from 2012-ish describing glitches and hacks.

Comment: I doubt anyone outside of the Diablo III dev team at Blizzard could answer this definitively. It's probably confirmation bias on his part to be honest. In other news, I heard having 4+ unidentified legendaries in your bag on D3 makes Onyxia deep breath more!

Comment: @JonK That was my reasoning as well, however my friend claims to have found a source, but doesn't seem to want to show me where it was. It makes me think it's just speculation and coincidence, but I figured I might as well ask.

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks, didn't realize there was an over-arching tag for D3 on console.

Comment: This is in all likelihood a rumour. I'd guess it originated from D2, where it was beneficial to have certain unique items in inventory, to maximize drop chances for variants of this item class (Stone of Jordan, the de-facto currency item, would only drop if the player possesed the two other ring variants).